# need a select query? count the number of id's which appear unique time?

Tags: mysql

need a select query it should count the cat_id from table 
[output should be 4][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaQmC.png`output 4`

Comment: Try this. SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select COUNT (DISTINCT cat_id)
from table_name
```

Comment: thanks bro.......its working

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  count(cat_id), time
FROM table_name group by time
having count(time)=1
```

you can check similar logic here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_having
with this query:

SELECT  count(CustomerID), Country
FROM Customers group by country 
having count(country)=1